# HOC the right way?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I have written two versions of HOC implementation by mistake but it doesn't throw me any mistakes and working as expected, so I'm hoping someone would be able to explain me the differences. `requireAuth` is the higher-order-component

First I have a component as below

```
import requireAuth from 'somepath';

class App extends Component {
  ...
}

export default connect(null, actions)(requireAuth(App));
```

Then below is my `requireAuth`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default (ChildComponent) => {
  class ComposedComponent extends Component {
    ...

    render() {
      return <ChildComponent {...this.props}/>;
    }
  }


  function mapStatetoProps(state) {
    return { someProp: state.someState };
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(ComposedComponent);
};
```

And below is my another version by mistake, but no error and I am looking for some explanation if there is any differences:

```
import requireAuth from 'somepath';

class App extends Component {
  ...
}

export default requireAuth(connect(null, actions)(App));//<<=== use requireAuth to surround the whole connect statement instead
```

And below is the `requireAuth`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export default (ChildComponent) => {
  class ComposedComponent extends Component {
    ...

    render() {
      return <ChildComponent />; //<<<======without {...this.props}
    }
  }


  function mapStatetoProps(state) {
    return { someProp: state.someState };
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(ComposedComponent);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing one needs to keep in mind using HOC is that, any react component that is wrapped within a HOC , will still yield a react component.

In the first case:

`connect(null, actions)(requireAuth(App));`

will provide redux props to `requireAuth`. Which is passing its props to `App` component. So the App component is still getting all the props from redux. So it works as far as I know.

For The second case:

`requireAuth(connect(null, actions)(App))`

you are passing `connect(null,actions)(App)` to the `requireAuth` component, as a children component. And only rendering the children component `return <ChildComponent />`. Since the `App` component is still wrapped by `connect`. The `App` component will still have all the redux props needed for its execution. So rendering `ChildComponent` without props will still work.
And the props obtained from `return { someProp: state.someState };` is still usable to `requireAuth`, because `requireAuth` is wrapped within another connect which will provide `requireAuth` the required props from the react state.

So both of the cases look alright theoretically. HOC are there to make our lives better instead of confusing. The first case you present is actually the right way to do things with HOC imo;